# How to perform String replacements without backslash escaping in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, replace, escaping

Consider the code:

```rb
output = `cat test.txt`
puts output  # /^\\([0-3][0-9]\\/[0-1][0-9]\\/[2-9][0-9]{3}\\)$/
str = 'test ' + output
puts str     # test /^\\([0-3][0-9]\\/[0-1][0-9]\\/[2-9][0-9]{3}\\)$/
new_str = 'new test ' + output
puts new_str # new test /^\\([0-3][0-9]\\/[0-1][0-9]\\/[2-9][0-9]{3}\\)$/

res = str.sub('test', 'new test')
puts res     # new test /^\\([0-3][0-9]\\/[0-1][0-9]\\/[2-9][0-9]{3}\\)$/ <-- all fine
res = str.sub(str, new_str)
puts res     # new test /^\([0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/[2-9][0-9]{3}\)$/     <-- !!! problem
```

code is just for presenting the problem which I have ;)

**Problem:** I have replacement text with double backslashes which I need to write "as it is" to another file

**Question is**: is there any simple replacement method which doesn't interpret backslashes (maybe some binary mode)?

Because it's kinda weird to do like this: `res = str.sub(str, new_str.gsub('\\', '\\\\\\\\'))`, although this works...

real working code:

```rb
file = 'some/random/file.php'
contents = new_contents = ''
File.open(file, 'rb') do |f|
  contents = new_contents = f.read
end

contents.scan(/('([A-Z]+)' \=\> \<\<\<'JSON'(.*?)JSON)/m) do |match|
  Dir.glob("*#{match[1]}.json") do |filename|
    compressed = `../compress.py #{filename}`.gsub('\\', '\\\\\\\\')
    replacement = match[0].sub(match[2], "\n" + compressed).force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')

    new_contents = new_contents.sub(match[0], replacement.gsub('\\', '\\\\\\\\'))
  end
end

File.open(file, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(new_contents)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I found pretty simple solution:

```rb
input = '{"regex": "/^\\\\([0-3][0-9]\\\\)$/"}'
puts input # gives => {"regex": "/^\\([0-3][0-9]\\)$/"}

search = '/^\\\\([0-3][0-9]\\\\)$/'
replace = '/^\\\\([0-9]\\\\)$/'

puts input.sub(search, replace) # gives => {"regex": "/^\([0-9]\)$/"}, which is wrong result

input[search] = replace # <-- here is the trick, but makes changes in place
puts input # gives => {"regex": "/^\\([0-9]\\)$/"} => success!
```

But! If your string doesn't contain any `search` substring you will get an `string not matched (IndexError)`.

So you may want to bulletproof your code like this:

```rb
input[search] = replace if input.include? search
```

Also, if you want to keep your `input` untouched you may `.dup` it to another variable:

```rb
new_input = input.dup
new_input[search] = replace if new_input.include? search
```

Comment: I see your problem. [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-sub) replacement strings can have backslashed references to matching portions, eg. "\1 \2", and therefore require backslashes themselves to be escaped.

Comment: exactly! but I don't need any backreferences, just plain substitution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace part of a string using a range. So you just have to find that range

```
if index = string.index(str_to_replace)
  string[index...(index + str_to_replace.length)] = replacement
end
```

This example does it in place, so do it to a dup if necessary.

Comment: good one! but I've came up with simpler solution ;) check my answer

Answer (score 0):

No, every Ruby String literal must escape backslashes. Ruby does allow arbitrary String *delimiters* like these:

```
%q{A string}
%Q<A string>
%.A string.
```

See [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) and [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation). However, these all treat backslashes as a special character and require that it be escaped.

One option is to put your replacements in a data file (eg. CSV) and read the replacements like this:

```
while line = data_file.gets
  pattern, replacement = *line.split(separator)
  str.gsub!(Regexp.compile(pattern), replacement)
end
```

The data file would **not** need to escape any characters in replacements.

Comment: if you take a closer look at my real code you will see that I'm already receiving replacement from external resource, so it's not a "double quoted string" or whatever. issue is in the `sub/gsub` methods, they are trying to interpret double backslashes and as the result I have only one backslash after substitution